# Access to "ServiceController" is denied through Web-Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

our webapplication is trying to access ServiceController (asp/c#) to Start/Stop a Service.
This is not a problem when the webapplication is deployed under "Default Web Site" and adding alias there.

However when we deploy the webapplication on another website (with another bindings) it cannot access the ServiceController and here is the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'our_website_name'. This operation might require other privileges.]
   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithAccess(String machineName, Int32 serviceControlManaqerAccess) +59255
   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithConnectAccess() +84
   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateNames() +46
   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_ServiceName() +49
   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateStatus() +107
   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_Status() +16
   the_function_that_call_ServiceController() +228
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

How can we fix this problem?

Comment: Seems like a permission issue to me. Do you have administrative privileges? Are you logging on to a Domain?

Comment: if you say that application running on the same server works on default site but doesn't on a different site, then I'd check what's the application pool user to see if they are the same

Comment: This is a security feature built into IIS.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: the application pool users are the same, i have tried using the administrator account on the app pool, still the same.

Comment: @AliAdl: yes, i have the administrative privileges and so is my website (i use my identity there)